# Why isn't there a store button under deployed contracts on Remix IDE

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, store, remix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w4e8.png)

I am using freecodecamp on youtube and on Remix IDE there is a store button under deployed contracts in the video but there isn't one on my end when I use Remix IDE

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are following this FreeCodeCamp YouTube tutorial:

'Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course – Beginner to Expert Python Tutorial'
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ

The store button is created within the store function during the demonstration of this video. Double-check that your code is as the tutorial is producing.

Here is an example store function that would produce a button within a Remix contract:

```
uint256 favoriteNumber;

function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
    favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30795820)

Comment: Thanks, 
I've added the store function. It should now be futureproofed.